# Getting 404 when updating from Spring Boot 2.0.X to 2.1.0

Tags: spring-boot

I have 2 integration tests passing with Spring Boot (2.0.X, probably with version 1.X as well) but when I use the latest version 2.1.0, the first one is failing, it returns 404 instead of 200...

Any idea?
I could not find any breaking change about this in the release note.

Thanks,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MockMvcExampleTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void testHomeUrl() throws Exception {
        this.mvc.perform(get("/home")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string("Hello World"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdminHomeUrl() throws Exception {
        this.mvc.perform(get("/admin/home")).andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class MyTestConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("USER").and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }
    }

    @Controller
    public static class TestController {

        @RequestMapping(path = "/home")
        public ResponseEntity<String> home() {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello World");
        }

        @RequestMapping(path = "/admin/home")
        public ResponseEntity<String> adminHome() {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello World Secured");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It may be related to [Spring boot 2.1.0 release Getting 404 not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53100730/spring-boot-2-1-0-release-getting-404-not-found-error), I could not find my answer there.

Comment: I've opened an issue on Spring Boot github, I have the feeling this is not normal... [Getting 404 instead of 200 with integration tests when updating from Spring Boot 2.0.X to 2.1.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15061)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I got an answer from the Spring Boot community.
I needed to annotate my `TestController` with `@TestConfiguration`.
Both tests are passing now.